# Django: object and reference object fields access

Tags: django

I have two class in my `models.py` file:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AssetTimeSeries(models.Model):    
    asset= models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='asset')    
    date = models.DateField()
    contribution = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    irr_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)
    quarter_highlights = models.TextField()
```

and I defined `views.py` code like this:

```
class AssetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Asset
    context_object_name = 'asset'
    template_name = 'asset/asset_detail.html'
```

and this is the `asset_detail.html` file:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="asset-detail">
    <h2>{{ asset.name }}</h2>
    <p>Short name: {{ asset.short_name }}</p>
    {% for asset_time_series in asset.asset.all %}
        <p>{{ asset_time_series.quarter_highlights }}</p>
        <p>{{ asset_time_series.irr_value}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>
        <h3>Asset history</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Contribution</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for asset_time_series in asset.asset.all %}
              <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>{{ asset_time_series.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ asset_time_series.contribution }}</td>
              </tr>                
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Is there a clever way to get last inserted values of the `AssetTimeSeries` object related to an `Asset` objects?

I mean can I rewrite this code to show me only the last values? instead of all the values?

```
{% for asset_time_series in asset.asset.all %}
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.quarter_highlights }}</p>
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.irr_value}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `asset.asset.all` doesn't mean anything in the context you provided. Did you forget to copy/paste the ForeignKey's `related_name`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I re-wright the code to copy&paste few lines. I think the `related_name` should be `asset= models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='asset') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way the the 'last_value' context will be the last, the you can use it in your template with {{ last_value }}

```
class AssetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Asset
    context_object_name = 'asset'
    template_name = 'asset/asset_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['last_value'] = AssetTimeSeries.objects.all().filter(asset=object.pk).order_by('-date').first()
        return context
```

the "object" variable have a reference of the current Asset, that way you can use object.pk to filter all timeseries of the current Asset and then order descending by date and get the first record

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but if I'm running your code I got this error: `type object 'AssetTimeSeries' has no attribute 'filter'`. However if I use this one `context['last_value'] = AssetTimeSeries.objects.all().filter(asset=self.object).order_by('-date').first()` the code is working

Comment: thats correct! with the all() function you get a Queryset where you can do filter()

Answer (score 0):

Use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter. Example, looping over "5 last items":

```
{% for asset_time_series in asset.asset.all | slice:"-5:" %}
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.quarter_highlights }}</p>
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.irr_value}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, add a new method to your Asset model so you can easily retrieve the last time series:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def last_items(self, nb=5):
        return self.asset.all()[-5:]
```

then use it directly in your template:

```
{% for asset_time_series in asset.last_items %}
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.quarter_highlights }}</p>
    <p>{{ asset_time_series.irr_value}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can use the second approad to perform more complex filters and directly use the result in the template. This is convenient since Django teamplate system doesn't support calling model methods with arguments (unlike Jinja2 for example). Keep in mind that you should have "Fat models, thin views"

Comment: Thank you for your help. However want show only the last value of the series, the code proposed by @guillermo-silva is one suit my needs. Than you!